# Backup options for Jira and confluence if the jumpbox failed to take one

Tags: shell, azure-devops, jira, confluence

So we have a weekly backup set in Jumpbox for both azure and confluence, however we noticed when our jumpbox was down, it missed the backup. What are the possible solutions in case like this

So this is a weekly cronjob.@